# Sending emails via NodeMailer in MERN Stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, email, gmail

I have a question about the whole process, I managed to finish a reset password flow via email, but the emails that I'm sending are going into spam. Do you guys know a way for my emails to go into the inbox and not into the spam folder? Did you ever met this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try gmail credentials

https://kb.synology.com/en-global/SRM/tutorial/How_to_use_Gmail_SMTP_server_to_send_emails_for_SRM

if it works, you have to change the domain of your user credentials

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the DKIM (DomainKeys Identified Mail) ?

Test the Spammyness of your Emails: https://www.mail-tester.com/